# Local storage getting cleared from the browser when I restart the app

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, persistent-storage, redux-persist

I have a webpage built on react js and redux. When I change the state of the app it also gets stored and updated in the local storage so that the user does not have to login again and again unless he logs out.

But the problem I am facing, when I reopen the page, is my local storage is getting cleared.

I am not facing this issue when I am running this code on the localhost using **npm run start**. This problem only comes in the production build.

I am using react-scripts for building the code.

I am saving and loading state from the local storage using the below code:

```
export const loadState = () => {
    try {
      const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
      if (serializedState === null) {
        return undefined;
      }
      return JSON.parse(serializedState);
    } catch (err) {
      return undefined;
    }
  }; 

export const saveState = (state: any) => {
    try {
      const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
      localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
    } catch {
      // ignore write errors
    }
  };
```

And I am creating the store using the below code:

```
export default () => {
    const savedState = loadState();
    let store: any;
    if(savedState){
        store = createStore(reducer, savedState, middleware);
    } else {
        store = createStore(reducer, {}, middleware);
    }

    store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
        saveState(store.getState());
    }, 1000))

    return {store};
};
```

I also tried using PersistGate from redux-persist as another approach to fix this problem but this problem is coming on PersistGate too.